# UK National Insurance Number

Tags: united-kingdom, social-security

I am non UK citizen since I don't live in UK I would like to find out if my National Insurance Card is still valid I had my card in year between 1970 - 1972.

Answer (score 4):

The numbering scheme changed after yours was assigned, but if you still have your *permanent* number you can do an online check at [Check your National Insurance record](https://www.gov.uk/check-national-insurance-record).

The same site lists a telephone number you can call for help, and a snail mail address you can use if the other methods fail.

If your number was a temporary number issued in the 1970's or earlier, then there will be no record of it today.

Comment: It is understand the numbering scheme has changed but I still have employee leaving copy so what would be the next step...

Comment: @AnisHaroon, answer updated